# What does 可是 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

A daughter to her police father,

> "How did you find me?" “你怎么找到我的？”

> "I'm a detective." “我**可是**个警探。”

可是 means

> but however yet

But it doesn't make sense here.

Comment: “我可是个警探。” "Come on. I'm a f-word detective.”

Comment: Two meanings for ```可是```: 1. but. 2. indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here 可是 is two words 可 + 是 and not one word: 可是. Here 可 + 是 is an adverbial phrase that it used to emphasize something. Take a look at Pleco C-E's definition:

> ADVERB
> [for emphasis]
>
> 这鱼可是新鲜的。
> Zhè yú kě shì xīnxiān de.
> The fish is really fresh.
>
> 说话可是要算数的。
> Shuōhuà kě shì yào suànshù de.
> You can never go back on your word.

Answer (score 1):

This 可 is to emphasize the statement. In English you would just pronounce "is" or "am" emphatically.

“我可是个警探。”
I ***am*** a detective.

这可是最大的一块蛋糕。
This is the biggest piece of cake.

我可是我们班最高的。
I am the tallest in our class.